# Display multiple rows of data in multiple tables or multiple frames.

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want, data from select query should display in multiple tables or frames rather than in multiple rows.
It means whatever data comes from select query, it should display each customer (lets say) data in a particular table or frame.
How can i do this ?

Comment: 0 down vote favorite
share [g+] share [fb] share [tw]
 

I want, data from select query should display in multiple tables or frames rather than in multiple rows. It means whatever data comes from select query, it should display each customer (lets say) data in a particular table or frame. How can i do this.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your currently using a GridView and applying a datasource and binding?  If so, to create 'one' table or frame or whatever HTML element, you can utilise the [DataRepeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and create the table within the 'ItemTemplate'.  However, depending on how you've structured the data (i.e. you're not applying any grouping to the dataset) you may need to [nest repeaters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6140/A-quick-guide-to-using-nested-repeaters-in-ASP-NET) or manipulate the data through the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Lastly, a more powerful approach, but time-consuming, would be creating a [custom web control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx) where *you* render out the HTML code as you see fit.